# How can I install docker on a VM using devcontainer.json?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I want to automate the installation of docker and docker-compose on a newly created VM. Ideally this should be done from the *devcontainer.json* file such that if a developer opens the project the Debian/Ubuntu packages *docker.io* and *docker-compose* are installed automatically.

I tried adding

```json
"initializeCommand": "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install -y docker.io docker-compose",
```

to the main hirarchy of *devcontainer.json* but it will not run before VS Code starts creating the container. VS Code gives an error message that Docker is not installed, although the `initializeCommand` command is supposed to be run before the container setup.

Is there any other way of achieving this except using additional tools or e.g. Azure VM templates?

Comment: `VS Code gives an error message that Docker is not installed` because devcontainer is a docker container which you need docker installed.

Comment: But the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_lifecycle-scripts) say regarding *initializeCommand*:  `A command string or list of command arguments to run on the host machine before the container is created.`

Comment: [devcontainer system requirement](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_system-requirements) mention you need to install docker first before you can use it.

Comment: Before the devcontainer program execute `initializeCommand`, it fail to execute because there is no docker installed in your host machine. Also, what you try to do is install docker inside a docker container. Are you sure that is what you want?